# TensorFlow Estimator 1.3 no way to get predict_proba?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I see the new DNN and estimator classes in 1.3 (tf.estimator.DNNClassifier) but I don't see any way to get/set predict_proba..

So as of now a prediction is set to true at over .5 % and false if under for the binary case I guess.. but there are numerous use cases where a lower probability to predict true, is very useful, particularly with very unbalanced data?

Any advice or leads? or guidance?

BTW it is available here:
class tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier

Comment: what about getting `inputs` and 'predictions` `tensor` from the `graph` and running the prediction manually.

Comment: Dunno, How would that work? (I'm struggling with the higher api!)

Comment: using the checkpoint `.*meta` file you can get the saver and restore the weights from the same checkpoint. then using `graph.get_tensor_by_name` to get the input and prediction tensor.

Comment: I can see a `predict_proba()` method on the [documentation DNNClassifier](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/DNNClassifier#predict_proba)

Comment: That is tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier contained in r1.2 not the DNN in the estimator class in 1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Google at GitHub: You can use tf.estimator now with e.g. predict(..., predict_keys="probabilities")

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/12119#issuecomment-321098690